# Getting the average rating from a book in a bookstore api

Tags: django, django-queryset, average

Written in python. I am having an issue that the average won't work on my code. I don't know if I can use annotate or aggregate. I want it so I can choose what book I want and show the average once I choose it.

```
class AverageRatingViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookratingsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Bookratings.objects.all()


        try:
            user_input = self.request.query_params.get('rating')
        except AttributeError as abc:
            return Bookratings.objects.none()

        if user_input is not None:
           **** ***queryset = queryset.filter(bookid=user_input).aggregate(Books_average=Avg('rating')*)****
**
            return queryset
```

I started messing around with the queryset.filter but I keep getting error on the local host

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: when I go launch the server and go to find  a book on http://127.0.0.1:8000/Bookratings/AverageRating/?rating=2 the server website just gives an error but it always says: AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `userid` on serializer `. I don't know why it keeps saying userID when I am trying to get bookID

Comment: You're filtering on `bookid`